# How to cast string to HttpFilePostedBase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ajax-upload

Is there a way how to convert the string to HttpFilePostedBase?
I'm currently using the [Ajax File upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) . But the value that it return is string. But my method is requesting for `HttpFilePostedBase` is there a way how to cast or convert it to `HttpFilePostedBase`?

here's my sample method in uploading files.

```
public bool uploadfiles(HttpPostedFileBase filedata)
{
bool status = false;
//code for uploading goes here
return status;
}
```

How can i call this method if the ajax file upload is passing a string?

Comment: Why does your `uploadfiles` method expect an `HttpPostedFileBase`?  You probably want to get the file via `Request.Files[0]`.

Comment: Hi. I try this one `var x = Request.Files[0];` but i get this error.

`Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index`

Comment: That means the page is not receiving any uploaded file.  You need to debug on the client side why it's not being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using IE or Chrome/Firefox? cause, different browsers upload files in a different manner. IE uploads the files through Requres.Files but others use `qqfile` in the query string.
Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884920/mvc3-valums-ajax-file-upload) on how to use valums with mvc for different browsers

EDIT: Okay then, how about this. This is an example which worked for me:

```
        public void ControllerUploadHandler()
    {
        // Set the response return data type
        this.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

        try
        {
            // get just the original filename
            byte[] buffer = new byte[Request.ContentLength];
            if (Request.QueryString["qqfile"] != null)
            {
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(this.Request.InputStream))
                    br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            else if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase httpPostedFileBase = Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase;
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(httpPostedFileBase.InputStream))
                    br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            else
                this.Response.Write(" {'success': false }");

            // return the json object as successful
            this.Response.Write("{ 'success': true }");
            this.Response.End();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // return the json object as unsuccessful
            this.Response.Write("{ 'success': false }");
            this.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I'm currently testing my sample in Firefox.
i try to copy the code, but it has an 
`error Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Temp\100\Koala.jpg'.`
do i need to create a `temp` folder and inside it i will create another folder name `100`? - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You can access files posted to an aspx page via the `HttpContext.Request.Files` property.