# Cannot read file uploaded in c# handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I'm trying to upload a file to a handler in c# but it seems as though the file is not getting uploaded. Calling `Request.Files["fileNameHere"]` returns null

My html code:

```
<form id="importManagerForm" action="../ImportManager.ashx" method="POST">
   <input name="selectedFile" id="selectedFile" type="file" /> 
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And the code in the ashx handler is:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
  var importFile = context.Request.Files["selectedFile"]; //This part returns null
  var fileName = new Guid().ToString() + ".csv";
  importFile.SaveAs(fileName);
}
```

Any idea what's the problem?

UPDATE:

A quick debug on `context.Request.Files` showed me a file count of 0.

Comment: Just ran a quick debug. The file count is 0.

Comment: Are you using IE, Chrome or FF?

Comment: I try this code but I still get count=0, any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on your form.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the html form control instead of the asp.net form server control.

You will need to set the `enctype`

```
<form id="importManagerForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      action="../ImportManager.ashx" method="POST">
```

Only then will you be able to receive files

Comment: +1 Worked great. Thanks :) Wish I could accept more than 1 answer though. Methieu posted first. Sorry

Comment: He beat me by 20 secs! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we have a file to be uploaded in html form or whenever we are using  tag in the form we have to notify the browser that the request contains binary data.
Hence it achieve this you have to add a **enctype** attribute to the  tag.

enctype="multipart/form-data" should be added to form.

it denotes that no characters are encoded before sent. i.e. it ensure that no character is encoded before sending the data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The browser may be the cause. If you are using IE the files will be in `Request.Files`, but in Chrome and FF the files are in `Request.QueryString["qqfile"]` 
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824642/how-to-cast-string-to-httpfilepostedbase/11825059#11825059) an example with code

Comment: They are speaking about a specific ajax plugin. Nothing to do with the browsers in general.

Comment: It's me speaking actually :D I had that issue and thought that that browser issue is general not only plugin specific. Thanks.