# mvc 4 razor upload a file without submitting the page form

Tags: .net, file, razor, upload, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing an MVC 4 app and need to allow the user to upload files, but don't want to submit the page's form when doing so. There is a bit of overhead in loading the whole form and I'd rather just update a partial on the page than reload it. I see this happening on other websites, but can't seem to get it to work for me.

Any hints?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Check out [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/). [Here](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3)'s a demo using ASP.NET MVC3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use: [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/#demo)

And will find MVC implementation here: [MVC Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884920/mvc3-valums-ajax-file-upload)